# pg_query expects Parameter 1 to be Resource, Boolean given... why?

Tags: php, postgresql

I must have read every single PostGreSQL and PHP tutorial on the internet trying to find an answer for this problem. Everytime I try to connect to the db it connects successfully, but instead of the variable being a usable connection resource, it a useless (at the moment) Boolean(true).

```
function startConnection(){
    $conn_str = "host=******** port=**** dbname=********* user=******* password=*********"; 

    $conn = pg_connect($conn_str)
        || die ("Connection Failed");

    if ($conn){
        echo('Successfully Connected: ');
        var_dump($conn);
    } else {
        echo('You Done Goofed');
    }

    $query_str = "SELECT * FROM **********";
    $query = pg_query($conn,$query_str);
    if($query) {
        echo ("Well Done, you fixed it");
    } else {
        echo ("You Done Goofed");
    }
}
```

Any help would be massively appreciated, I'm sure its just a stupid mistake that I have made somewhere.

Comment: How would I fix it then?

Comment: Don't `die` with messages like `"Connection Failed"` or `'You Done Goofed'`, that's not very helpful.  Try to get the *real* error messages with `pg_last_error()` or `pg_connection_status()`.

Comment: This is literally a 2 minute function to try and correct the error for a larger PHP script. I'm not normally this unprofessional, honest

Comment: @Kamon241: Check [@Marc B's](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20077148/206403) answer, I think he hit the nail on the head.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your connect call is incorrect. You need to use the `or` operator, not `||`. They work the same, but `or` has a LOWER [binding precedece](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.precedence.php) than `||`. Try

```
$conn = pg_connect(...) or die('failed');
```

Comment: I don't understand how that would make a difference here.  If `pg_connect` returns `FALSE` wouldn't it `die` either way?  Look at my test here: https://eval.in/69882

Comment: WAIT.  Never mind.  I see!  `||` goes before `=` which goes before `or`.  So, he's setting `$con` to the result of the `||` call, versus the result of the `pg_connect` call (when using `or`)!  New test: https://eval.in/69888